# Grails sortableColumn using Object Id instead of Name

Tags: sorting, grails, object

I have a list of resources that have managers which are also resources in my system. I want to sort the list of resource by their names. What I am finding is that Grails is sorting the list by the resource Id and not the field that I am specifying.

```
<g:sortableColumn property="orgRole" title="Org Role" />

<g:each in="${resourceInstanceList}" status="i" var="resourceInstance">
   <td>${fieldValue(bean: resourceInstance, field: "manager")}</td>
   <!--<td> ${resourceInstance.manager.toString()} </td>-->
</g:each>
```

I have defined the static mapping on my resource to sort by my 'name' attribute and I have a toString method that I have tried calling that also returns the 'name' of the object as the value. Still seeing the list sorted by the Integer 'id' attribute that is tied to the sequence in the database.

Comment: What does the controller code look like?  Sortable columns work by generating links to `/controller/action?sort=theProperty&order=asc`, and you have to pass these parameters through to the `DomainClass.list()` or `.findAllByX()` call for the sorting to actually happen.

Answer (score 0):

The precision needs to be defined on the sortableColumn and not on the td. I should have used this:`<g:sortableColumn property="orgRole.name" title="Org Role" />` this explicitly tells Grails which field I want to use, otherwise it relies on the default id element of the object.